# How to block writes to standard output in java (System.out.println())

Tags: java, logging, stdout

**In Java, how to block code from writing to system out?**
My app calls a 3rd party library that spams logs by issuing numerous System.out.println() calls.
I don't have legal rights to decompile and patch the library.
I'm running Websphere 8.5.x

Considered using [System.setOut(PrintStream out)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut-java.io.PrintStream-), but that will effect the entire process, while I only want to limit the effect to a single thread.

Comment: edit: sorry. Not complete at all for your question.

Comment: I suppose you already know, but what you need to do is figure out what logging framework is used, and change logging level in configurations for that library. I don't think any sensible library should use system.out for output. If yes, then it's a huge bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can identify the thread you want to "mute" reliably somehow (e.g. by name), you can `setOut` to your own stream which will only delegate the calls to the actual `System.out` if they don't come from the muted thread.